# How do I set Reciprocating and Rotation motion in Fluent or CFX?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, cfd, waves

I want to model the following case(Attached picture)

[image]

This case have reciprocating and rotation motion. Is it possible that this case models in Fluent or CFX  without writing Code?

How i set this reciprocation motion in CFX? Is it possible that give me related paper and useful links and tutorials about this case? I found documentations about this case but don't found tutorial about this case.

Comment: In fluent, you'd do this with a Dynamic Zone and specifying the motion with a UDF or a profile.